# $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)\in \mathbb{Z}$ for $\alpha\in\mathrm{cl}_L(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension, $H=\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathrm{Tr}:L\to L$ the trace map, given by
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\alpha).$$
I showed that $\mathrm{Tr}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear and $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $\alpha\in L$. But I have not been able to justify that $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $a\in\mathrm{cl}_L(\mathbb{Z})$.

Here, $\mathrm{cl}_L(\mathbb{Z})$ denotes the integer closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $L$. Could someone give me an idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you relate the trace to the coefficients of the minimal polynomial?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316115/connection-between-galois-trace-and-matrix-trace) for the minimal polynomial.

Comment: I see. $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)=-\frac{n}{d}z_{d-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $n=[L:\mathbb{Q}]$, $d=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $z_{d-1}$ is the coefficient in $p(x)=x^d+z_{d-1}x^{d-1}+\cdots+z_1x+z_0$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**

- Show  that if $\alpha\in cl_L(\mathbb{Z})$, then for all $\sigma\in H$, $\sigma(\alpha)\in cl_L(\mathbb{Z})$
- Deduce that $Tr(\alpha)\in cl_L(\mathbb{Z})\cap\mathbb{Q}$
- Conclude

Comment: What does $\sigma_L(\alpha)$ mean? Or do you mean $\mathrm{Tr}_L(\sigma)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if one can prove that $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)\in\mathrm{cl}_L(\mathbb{Z})$ (without proof $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)\in\mathbb{Z}$) because in general $\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha^n)\neq\mathrm{Tr}(\alpha)^n$.

Comment: $\sigma(\alpha)$, not $\sigma_L(\alpha)$. I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ inside $L$.  For every $\sigma \in G = \operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$, and every $x \in R$, you also have $\sigma(x) \in R$.  Therefore,

$$\operatorname{Tr}(x) = \sum\limits_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x) \in R.$$

But also $\operatorname{Tr}(x) \in \mathbb Q$ as you have mentioend.  So $\operatorname{Tr}(x) \in \mathbb Q \cap R = \mathbb Z$.